# Api-platform - docker. What is the best way to consume messenger buses from then a containerized service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, api-platform.com, symfony-messenger

I'm interested to know your opinions.

By working from the api platform stack (https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform),

I want to minimize manual intervention on the deployment of my project

I added a rabbitmq container ...

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.9-management-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER:-guest}
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS:-guest}
    ports: [5672, 15672]

  php:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: app_php
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-app}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}
      TRUSTED_PROXIES: ${TRUSTED_PROXIES:-127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16}
      TRUSTED_HOSTS: ^${SERVER_NAME:-example\.com|localhost}|caddy$$
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}

  pwa:
    build:
      context: ./pwa
      target: prod
    environment:
      NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy

  caddy:
    build:
      context: api/
      target: app_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
      - pwa
    environment:
      PWA_UPSTREAM: pwa:3000
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}, caddy:80
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp

  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
  db_data:
```

I want to automate the execution of the command **bin/console messenger:consume async** in a service..

What do you think is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

ALL RIGHT.
Here is the solution I found.

I created a second service similar to the php service whose role is to execute messenger

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.9-management-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER:-guest}
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS:-guest}
    ports: [5672, 15672]

  php:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: app_php
    depends_on:
      - database
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-app}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}
      TRUSTED_PROXIES: ${TRUSTED_PROXIES:-127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16}
      TRUSTED_HOSTS: ^${SERVER_NAME:-example\.com|localhost}|caddy$$
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}

  php-consume:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: app_php
    image: app_php
    depends_on:
      - php
      - rabbitmq
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER:-app}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}@database:5432/${POSTGRES_DB:-app}?serverVersion=${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}
      TRUSTED_PROXIES: ${TRUSTED_PROXIES:-127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16}
      TRUSTED_HOSTS: ^${SERVER_NAME:-example\.com|localhost}|caddy$$
      MERCURE_URL: ${CADDY_MERCURE_URL:-http://caddy/.well-known/mercure}
      MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL: https://${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}/.well-known/mercure
      MERCURE_JWT_SECRET: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}
    command: ["bin/console", "messenger:consume", "async", "-vv"]

  pwa:
    build:
      context: ./pwa
      target: prod
    environment:
      NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy

  caddy:
    build:
      context: api/
      target: app_caddy
    depends_on:
      - php
      - pwa
    environment:
      PWA_UPSTREAM: pwa:3000
      SERVER_NAME: ${SERVER_NAME:-localhost}, caddy:80
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: ${CADDY_MERCURE_JWT_SECRET:-!ChangeThisMercureHubJWTSecretKey!}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - php_socket:/var/run/php
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - target: 80
        published: ${HTTP_PORT:-80}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTPS
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTPS_PORT:-443}
        protocol: tcp
      # HTTP/3
      - target: 443
        published: ${HTTP3_PORT:-443}
        protocol: udp

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-14}-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # you may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./api/docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

# Mercure is installed as a Caddy module, prevent the Flex recipe from installing another service
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###

volumes:
  php_socket:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
```